# How to replace nodes in a d3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a d3.js force layout graph to display js objects. Every object corresponds to a node in the graph, and each node is represented in the DOM by an SVG <g> element.

I have everything working fine, except for replacing a node object with a new, updated object. When I attempt to do this, d3 seems to be removing the old <g> and it's contents and adding a new one *with the old data*.

Ideally, I'd like to have d3 simply update the existing elements for that object with the new data.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d3query/xf66gxo8/1/

Clicking on the update button should replace the last node with different data. This works if I update the object's properties:

```
dataset[index].name = 'four';
```

but not if I replace the object outright:

```
dataset[index] = { id: oldnode.id, name: 'four' };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first associate the data with the selection

```
var elems = ddisp.selectAll('g').data(dataset, function(d) { return d.id; });
```

you're associating a JavaScript object with the SVG `<g>` element.

The statement

```
dataset[index].name = 'four';
```

changes a property of the existing object. So when you re-run `render` D3 is able to pick up that new property. It's still reading the old object, but the object's `name` property has changed.

By contrast, when you execute the statement

```
dataset[index] = { id: oldnode.id, name: 'four' };
```

you're changing an element in the array by creating a **new object,** but the SVG `<g>` element is still associated with the old object. It's true that you're calling

```
ddisp.selectAll('g').data(dataset, function(d) { return d.id; });
```

again with the updated array, but you haven't changed the `id` property (and you've told D3 that the `id` property is what determines the "uniqueness" of a data point). So when D3 comes to the "new" element in the array, it checks the `id` value, sees that nothing has changed (it's still 2), and, therefore, doesn't update the object associated with that `<g>` element.

If, instead, you responded to the update button with

```
dataset[index] = { id: 4, name: 'four' };
```

then you would indeed see the node updated because, by changing the `id` property, you would have signaled to D3 that the array element was new.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that clears some things up for me. A few things I'm still confused about, though:

Comment: (sorry about the double post, I can't edit my previous comment) Thanks for the response, that clears some things up for me. A few things I'm still confused about, though: 1) If I remove the data index function, I still get the same behavior. 2) When I replace an object and d3 creates a new element, is that old data coming from some internal cache (in d3) of the original object?

Comment: 1: I don't see a "data index function" so I don't understand the question. 2: When you replace an object D3 does NOT create a new element.

Comment: 1: the function passed as the second parameter to data()  2: that makes sense, I think I get it now

Comment: Ah. Yes, if you don't specify a function that D3 should use to uniquely identify your data points (what you've called a "data index function"), then D3 just uses the position in the array as an unique identifier. Since you're not changing the length of the array, D3 again doesn't think any data has changed.